# Get value of local variable based on variable name

Tags: javascript, eval, scope

I was wondering if it is possible to access a variable (i.e. get the value of that variable) by using the name of that variable. An example would be:

```
function myObject(){
   var x = 1;
   this.get = function(varName){return eval(varName);};
}
var test = new myObject();
test.get("x");
```

I know this is possible with eval, but I was wondering if the same could be done without the use of eval, like i.e. with *Function*. (The use of eval is not allowed in the framework I'm using.)

Comment: This question has been asked a thousand times. The answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

You can access global variables as an associative array, like this:

```
var x = 5;
var variableName = "x";
window[variableName];
```

In your case, you can return `this[varName]`, if you replace `var x` with `this.x`.

Comment: This would indeed be a solution for the globally defined variables. However, I would like to only access the locally defined variables (in this case x).

Comment: This is the only way to do it. Just use this.x or write out your accessors.

Comment: There are no associative arrays in javscript, there are just objects (even arrays are basically plain objects with a special *length* property and some mostly generic methods). And *this* references a real object, it has nothing to do with variables.